# How to get a record in the database provided

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have UserEntity

```
@Entity("users")

export class UserEntity {

... 

@ManyToMany(()=> DialogEntity,(dialog)=> dialog.members)

@JoinTable()

dialogs: DialogEntity[]
```

Also I have a DialogEntity

```
@Entity("dialogs")

export class DialogEntity {

... 

@ManyToMany(()=> UserEntity,(user)=> user.dialogs)

members: UserEntity[]
```

In the dialogs column of UserEntity I have two users and I need to find the dialog so that the members column is exactly like the array I will pass it to (For example: I have users with id 1 and 2, I need to find the dialog so that in in the members column, one of the users was with id 1, and the other 2). How can this be implemented?

I tried to do this: find all dialogs that have one of the users with id 1, and then iterate through this array and find the dialog that has the second user with id 2